# How can I redirect standard error to standard output in R - Sniny

Tags: redirect

I am looking for a way to capture standard error and redirect it to standard output in R (Shiny).  I can not find any information any where in the web.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I am trying the code below so that if there is neither "/" nor "\" the output is an error and the application stops, but ir does not work.
if(!grepl("/", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE) || !grepl("\\", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)){
       trueFalse = FALSE
       errorMessage("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath or no path specification in PARAMS file. Cannot open connection\n
                             You can edit your input file and save the changes. Afterwards, stop and restart glycoPipe and upload file again")
       stop("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath\n")
     }

Comment: I am trying the code below so that if there is neither "/" nor "\" the output is an error and the application stops, but ir does not work.

       if(!grepl("/", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE) || !grepl("\\", OUTpath, fixed=TRUE)){
       trueFalse = FALSE
       errorMessage("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath or no path specification in PARAMS file. Cannot open connection\n
                             You can edit your input file and save the changes. Afterwards, stop and restart glycoPipe and upload file again")
       stop("Unrecognized path separator in OUTpath\n")
     }

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1024119/edit) link to fix your question.  Using the comments for fixing your question is extremely hard to read.  The comments are mainly for users to ask for clarification, of which you would normally edit and make yout question clearer based on comments from others.

Answer (score 0):

This code works.  trueFalse and errorMessage are captured by the server by calling the function that produces that code and displayed by using renderText() in the server and textOutput() in the GUI

```
trueFalse = FALSE
       # capture all the output to a file.
        FILE <- file("log.txt", open = "wt")
        sink(FILE)
        sink(FILE, type = "message")
        #try(log("a"))
        try(message("Path does not exist. You can make changes to the PARAMS file.  Afterwards, stop and restart glycoPipe"))
        ## revert output back to the console -- only then access the file!
        sink(type = "message")
        sink()
        #file.show("log.txt")
        errorMessage <- (readLines("log.txt"))
```